# Possible to use Buddypress within an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, buddypress

I want to create a community for my venture and also an iphone application for the same. I am thinking of using Buddypress for the community.

But is it possible to use buddypress with an iPhone app? I'd like that when user posts a message via the iPhone app, it is also posted on buddypress? Or do I have to write custom scripts for editing the buddypress db according to user actions in the iPhone app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading about a plugin for BuddyPress, called BPDEV XMLRPC that allows you to communicate with BuddyPress via XMLRPC. I'm not sure if it's out of the development trunk yet, but it seems like you could use that to post messages to BuddyPress from an iPhone app. [bp-dev.org](http://bp-dev.org) seems to be down at the moment, but I read about it there.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to do -- but will require some heavy development work.  Would have to modify heavily a child theme and do lots of stuff to make it work.  Let me know if you find anything that works.

Comment: By now, it might also be possible to find a theme with buddypress support that is responsive and works on iPhone.